# Is there a default counter object in STL

Tags: c++, count, iterator, metaprogramming

I have a task where I have to count how many of different kinds of objects there are and save the result to later create graphs out of them. What I am doing is creating sorted vectors holding elements that satisfy different conditions, and calling `std::set_intersection` on them to find how many of them satisfy a composite statement. For example:

```
// Count round and black objects
std::vector<SomeObject*> roundAndBlackObjects;
std::set_intersection(roundObjects.begin(), roundObjects.end(),
    blackObjects.begin(), blackObjects.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(roundAndBlackObjects));
std::size_t numRoundAndBlackObjects = roundAndBlackObjects.size();
```

This seems to be too complex though. I only wanted to count the common elements after all. Is there a way to omit the unnecessary vector push_backs? Is there an easy way to do this? Something like an output iterator generator, that creates a dummy output iterator that does not construct anything, just counts the calls to its increments. That way I could do something like this:

```
// Count round and black objects
std::size_t numRoundAndBlackObjects = 0;
std::set_intersection(roundObjects.begin(), roundObjects.end(),
    blackObjects.begin(), blackObjects.end(),
    std::iterator_callback_counter<SomeObject*>(numRoundAndBlackObjects));
```

If there is no such thing, is there an easy way to create such a meta-object?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is too complex? It seems to me like what you are trying to do is a textbook example of a set intersection. I also don't understand what the title of your question means.

Comment: Boost has [counting_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html).

Comment: If you want to build a histogram a `std::map` works really well for that and only requires a linear traversal of the data set to populate it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The too complex part is the construction of a new vector instead of just counting.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi You can write your own output iterator for this. See the [OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) concept page at cppreference.com. You simply have to implement the four operations specified there and the two operations specified in the Iterator concept page. You can specialise [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for your new iterator type.

Comment: @NathanOliver I want something like 50 different histograms with some data-filtering reused.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi That shouldn't be to hard to do.  You could do a vector of maps or map of maps depending on how you wan to access the different histograms.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux can you point me to an example code of how I write something that is an OutputIterator?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think the implementation is relevant there. Using vectors for this kind of problem is much more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *almost* use a plain `int`.

`std::set_intersection` calls two operators on the output iterator, unary `operator*` and `operator++`. Calling the latter on `int` is how you count, but you need a wrapper to ignore `operator*`.

How do you ignore `operator*`? It must return something which allows `*iter = value`. Well, your wrapper could return `*this`. That just means `operator=` also gets called on your wrapper. That again can just return `*this`.

So, to put it all together :

```
class counter {
   size_t count = 0; // Let's count a bit further
public:
   counter& operator++() { ++count; return *this; }    // ++X
   counter& operator++(int) { ++count; return *this; } // X++
   counter& operator*() { return *this; }
   template<typename T> counter& operator=(T&&) { return *this; }
   counter& operator=(counter&) = default; // Don't break normal assignment.

   operator size_t() const { return count; }
};
```

Comment: Sugoi! This is what I was looking for, thank you. :)

Comment: Why the change? Was something wrong with the first code?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi: I added `operator++(int)` to allow `myCounter++`.